# how to ask what something is (input) then if they get it wrong it'll ask them again (while loop)

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm doing a GCSE in computing and starting a new code for fun and I'm having trouble like a noob. I am making a code asking them what the password is and if they get it wrong it'll ask again until the requirements are met, I have looked on the internet and it gave me a countdown on all of the websites I checked. this is my code so far...

```
password = 1234
passinput = (input("what is your password? "))
```

I have tried several things such as...

```
while True:
```

and

```
while False:
```

but I don't understand how to use them properly. I have learned it in class, but it's an easy thing to forget. I want the code to keep on asking the user until they input "1234" (the password)

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
while True:
    answer = input('password?')
    if answer == password:
        break
```

Fro more complex needs (or a better understanding of the options), see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: it keeps looping instead of breaking.

Comment: @ChimpeusStyx: try `password = "1234"`

Answer (score 0):

More simple way

```
password = 1234
while int(input()) != password: pass
```

Comment: this code just loops even if I put the password in

Comment: @ChimpeusStyx No, this loops only until you enter the correct password, i.e. 1234 here.

Answer (score 0):

The short way:

```py
while True:
    if input("what's the password? ") == "1234":
        break
```

Or even shorter:

```
while input("what's the password? ") != "1234":
    pass
```

Or if you'd insist on a one- liner:

```
while input("what's the password? ") != "1234": pass
```